# Can i chain observableList clear() and addAll() in one command?

Tags: java, combobox, observablelist

Based on user-selected options, my ComboBox needs to display different content. So i have to throw out the existing Items, and load a new List.

Currently i have (and this works)

```
    myComboBox.getItems().clear();
    myComboBox.getItems().addAll(myList);
```

However I want to chain them:

```
    myComboBox.getItems().clear().addAll(myList);
```

or:

```
    myComboBox.getItems().clear().getItems().addAll(myList);
```

but I get: void cannot be dereferenced as clear() has already returned void.

Is there some way to chain these actions ? 
It works but it's ugly and i vaguely recall seeing a more elegant solution but cannot remember what it was.

Comment: this comboBox is from java fx or is a JComboBox?

Answer (score 2):

If the combo box is from javaFX you can use this:

```
myComboBox.getItems().setAll(<collection>);
```

where  is any collection that will replace the existring one (Usually List or ArrayList).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do,

```
myComboBox = new ComboBox(myList);
```

Comment: sure he can but it will re-allocate the all calss and this is a very expensive procedure. If he doesn't care about little lose of performance is probably the simplest way

Comment: plain wrong - the question is about updating the combo's data (vs replacing the combo itself.. which would require also to remove/add the old/new combo from/to the ui)